# advice on how to reduce the polygon count for this twisted structure (made using simple transform)

Tags: mesh, transforms, edit-mode, topology

I'm working on a mirror made out of twisted pieces of metal for a game. However the current number of polygons is far to high does anybody know of a good way to reduce the number of polygons without creating very ugly artifacts within this mirror? [image]

The blender file can be found [here](http://www.filedropper.com/newmirroropt)

Comment: BTW this really needs some kind of " low poly" tag but I cannot make it

Comment: there's no low-poly tag : o

Comment: I know and I cannot make it but it seems like something that might be useful for a site such as this.

Comment: I'm looking into this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to use the decimate modifier to lower the poly count od your model and maybe add a smooth shading to hide some glitches :

[image]

the reduction result :

[image]

the model ( with smooth shading ) :

[image]